# Python Import All Modules in Changing Filename/Directory - From "Filename" import * ( Even if that particular filename changes )

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

I'm having trouble importing all modules `from ModuleName import *` given a Python Script with Functions in a different directory.

I have looked at and tried `importlib`, `__import__`, and various `sys.modules` code but I have been unable to dynamically `from changingFilename import *`

Assume I would like to do the following:

```
from MyBasicFunctions import *
```

I have a `MyBasicFunctions.py` file in completely different directory.

I want to write code that does a `from MyBasicFunctions import *` even if I later decide to change the name of my Module (via Renaming through the Windows OS) to `MySemiAdvancedFunctions.py`

I am constantly changing my Script Names as I add new functions that fit a theme different from what it was original.

I am trying to figure out how to do a `from MySemiAdvancedFunctions import *` without ever adjusting the Python Script that performs that import. I'd for Python to import `MySemiAdvancedFunctions` or any other name simply by determining whether a script is in a specified directory. So the Directory would be constant, and I would run something like an `os.listdir()` to get the new (renamed) filename and automatically import that into my static python script.

Is this even possible in Python?